# how to unserialize jquery serialized data in php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have sent the serialized data to PHP on form submission:

```
$('#new-store-pickup').on("click",function(){
    var businessHoursManager = $("#businessHoursContainer3").businessHours();
    $('#businesshourvalue').val(JSON.stringify(businessHoursManager.serialize()));
    $('#new-product-form').submit();
    return false;
});
```

The data format is below:

```
[{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null},{"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null}]
```

How do I unserialize the above data in PHP?

Comment: `json_decode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. However it's very odd that you're encoding the form to JSON and sending it in a standard request. Why not just send it using the standard form-urlencoding. All this is doing is pointlessly making extra work for yourself.

Comment: Look here hope it will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple use json_decode for decode json data in php

```
<?php
$json = '[{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},{"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null},{"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null}]' ;

echo "<pre>";
$converted = json_decode($json);
print_r($converted);

?>
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, worked perfectly, added  below code before json_decode,                                                     
 $json = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($json));

Comment: Welcome@karthickeyan